# How to check HTML5 app works or not?

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, html5-apps

I have a requirement where I can add both flash and **embed HTML5** app on page. But HTML5 app is not supported on many browsers. What I want to do is to **check at runtime if the HTML5 app is not working fine, then show Flash File**. But I don't know how can I check at run time whether my app is displaying anything or not. I have embedded the HTML5 code through following code in user-control:

```
<embed src='<fully qualified html5 app link>' height="<height>" width="<width>" />
```

Comment: Have a test browser on a vm that doesn't support HTML 5?

Comment: There is few tools to test whether html5 element is supported on current page load. I'm using `modernizr` to check it, and could work as `if-else`.

Comment: @Paddy: Yes. It's not working on any browser except chrome. FF shows plugin missing and IE shows a blank space with no error.

Comment: @grimv01k: Can u please explain a bit more on how to get this tool and usage?

Comment: Just google it, it's simple. I've posted a comment instead of detailed answer because I'm not sure what kind of app you are using and can you actually check that app 'outside' of it.

Answer (score 1):

The process of checking for supported functionality at runtime is often referred as "feature detection". Modernizr is one popular JavaScript library that provides such "feature detects": http://modernizr.com/

For example, let's start with the HTML you suggested, and add an `id` attribute for convenience:

```
<embed id="fancy" height="<height>" width="<width>" />
```

If you wanted to use HTML5 Canvas, for example, but had to fall back to a Flash alternative in non-Canvas browsers, you could do something like this (in JavaScript, with Modernizr):

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) {
    // TODO: do whatever it is you want to do with Canvas
} else {
    // hook up your embed to the fallback Flash component
    document.getElementById('fancy').src = 'url/for/flash/component.swf';
}
```

HTML5 covers loads of functionality. The precise "detect" required will vary based on your requirements, but Modernizr makes most of this quite simple.